# Creating adapter for Timestamp for JAXB conversion

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am currently trying the JAXB library for XML to POJO conversion. I have a class which as follows :

```
class Student {

 String name;
 Integer id;
 Date dateOfBirth;
 @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TimeDateAdapter.class)
 Timestamp admitTime;

 //constructor and getter setters

}
```

Now I want to input these fields via XML. So I reproduce xml something like :

```
  <student>
    <name>Student 1</name>
    <id>123</id>
    <dob>29-02-1991</dob>
    <admitTime>231441321413</admitTime>
  </student>
```

So, as you might know it will throw an error saying it cannot convert Timestamp since there is no no-arg constructor in Timestamp class. So I will have to create an Adapter. So, I was wondering if there is a way of creating a generic adapter for Date, timestamp and maybe Calendar as well so that they can be unmarshalled and marshalled according to the implementation?

EDIT: I created an Adapter for marshalling and unmarshalling my java.sql.Timestamp object from and to xml. Here is the code :

import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

```
public class TimeDateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Timestamp>{

    @Override
    public String marshal(Timestamp v) throws Exception {
        return v.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Timestamp unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return new Timestamp(Long.parseLong(v));
    }

}
```

Its giving me the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 3 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
There are two properties named "publishDate" 
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.sql.Timestamp Book.getPublishDate()
        at Book
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.sql.Timestamp Book.publishDate
        at Book
java.sql.Timestamp does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.sql.Timestamp
        at public java.sql.Timestamp Book.getPublishDate()
        at Book
Class has two properties of the same name "publishDate"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.sql.Timestamp Book.getPublishDate()
        at Book
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.sql.Timestamp Book.publishDate
        at Book

    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:472)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:248)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:235)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:432)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:637)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
    at BookMain.main(BookMain.java:42)
```

Comment: @StackOverflow community : Please contribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JAXB (JSR-222) implementations support `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` by default so you will not require an `XmlAdapter` for them.  Classes like `java.sql.Date`, `java.sql.Time`, and `java.sql.Timestamp` will require an `XmlAdapter`.  I would recommend separate adapters instead of trying to combine them into one.

**Note**

An `XmlAdapter` can be specified at the package level.  When doe this way it applies to all mapped fields/properties on that type belonging to domain classes in that package.  This can greatly reduce the amount of times you need to specify `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`.  You can read more about this approach on my blog.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxb-and-package-level-xmladapters.html

---

### UPDATE

```
There are two properties named "publishDate" 
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.sql.Timestamp Book.getPublishDate()
        at Book
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.sql.Timestamp Book.publishDate
        at Book
```

By default JAXB treats public properties (get/set method pairs) and annotated fields as mapped.  This is what's causing this part of the exception.  You need to do one of the following:

1. Annotate the get method instead of the field.
2. Keep the annotation on the field and specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on your class.

I have written more about this on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: Hi Blaise, I wrote an adapter that would marshal and unmarshal my java.sql.Timestamp to String and vice-versa. I am putting the code in the EDIT in a jiffy kindly check why its not working.

Comment: @Sourabh - In addition to the `XmlAdapter` can you point to where you registered it with an `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` and what you mean by it's not working (i.e. the stack trace)?

Comment: I registered it on top of the element of Timestamp class.

Comment: Thanks for terse description. I would also like to know in case I have an abstract class A that two concrete classes B and C extends. I have List<A> list; in a class how should unmarshall this? Using @XmlElements({@XmlElement(name="A", type = A.class},@XmlElement(name="B", type = B.class}) and making the same element @XmlElementWrapper(name="list")?

Comment: @Sourabh - Can you make that a new question?

Comment: Sure give me 5 min :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.sql.Timestamp;
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

    public class TimestampAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Timestamp> {
    
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS");

    @Override
     public Timestamp unmarshal(String value) throws Exception {
        return Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.parse(value, formatter));
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Timestamp timestamp) throws Exception {
        return timestamp.toLocalDateTime().format(formatter);
    }
}
```

Comment: While your code may solve the answer, adding some text explaining how and why this solves the problem would make it a better quality answer.